# Information retrieval and verification between android devices

Tags: android, database, cloud

I am trying to create an android application in which clients and service providers will interact with each other. The biggest obstacle I see is the information that would be coordinated between devices that are registered as service and non-service providers(clients). This information is mainly for payment purposes to the service providers and for verification of services being rendered to the client. I would need to generate strings and numerical information and verify in order to pay my service providers. The QUESTION is where should I store all this information. I have thought of different ideas such as, Google Cloud Messaging(I believe is capped at 100 messages per request or per day?), creating a website that would host a database that could be query from my app in order for verifications to occur, or verifying and storing information in email lists(probably I would have to hire personnel to do this: not what I want).

Also, I believe that Google cloud messaging might be appropriate, but I think I have to set up a server with my app and store information in it. Is it possible to store information on a server and retrieve it. I don't have slight idea on  how to do this.

Can someone please advise as to what would be the best avenue to take?

thank you